# REGEX : How to add list as condition to satisfy regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to check whether next sentence start with word which is already listed in wordList or not?

```
WordList = {Hello, Namshte, Hi, Hey ...... around 500 records- dummy list here }
```

Ex. This is 1st Sentence. This is 2nd place. **Hello,This is my 3rd Sentence.**

```
Requirement ->  "." + " " (space) + "<word from List>"
```

For Simple REGEX I can write "\.\s[A-Z]" start with Alphabet.
But I want to detect sentence which starts with word from List.

```
REGEX -> \.\s[???]   -> ? how to add List here
```

How does it select 3rd sentence properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression, given as a Java string:

```
"\\.\\s(?i:Hello|Namshte|Hi|Hey)\\b"
```

Explanation:

- `\\.` Match period
- `\\s` Match a whitespace
- `(?i:     )` Non-capturing group match case-insensitively.
- `Hello|Namshte|Hi|Hey` Match one of the words.
- `\\b` Match word boundary to prevent match on word like `Hijack`.

To select the entire 3rd sentence, meaning up to and including the next period, use this:

```
"\\.\\s((?i:Hello|Namshte|Hi|Hey)\\b[^.]+\\.)"
```

The capturing group is the sentence.

**Update** Code example:

```
String[] wordList = { "Hello", "Namshte", "Hi", "Hey", ...... 500 words };

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : wordList) {
    if (buf.length() != 0)
        buf.append('|');
    buf.append(Pattern.quote(word));
}
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s((?i:" + buf + ")\\b[^.]+\\.)");

String text = "This is 1st Sentence. This is 2nd place. Hello,This is my 3rd Sentence." +
              " This is 4th place. Namshte, at 5.";
Matcher m = regex.matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1));
```

*Output*

```
Found: Hello,This is my 3rd Sentence.
Found: Namshte, at 5.
```

Comment: Sir I have 500 of records. not only 4 . Using looping with each word and check , it would be very tedious job.

Comment: You add all 500 words to the expression, and let the Java Regular Expression engine do the work for you.

Comment: "\\.\\s((< word List >)\\b[^.]+\\.)"   , Cant we add list variable name directly ?

Comment: actually there is symbolic expression which helps to iterate list directly. We dont need to concatenate records.  I used it in past. but somehow i forgot. I didnt remember.

Comment: I think that might have been a different language, e.g. Perl.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use a loop structure. Your loop should be

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     if(sentence.contains(array[i])){
//print out the sentence
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of using [a-zA-z] , I have separate list which consist of 500 words. that I want to check with.

Comment: then you can make use of \w